# Java Card Technology for Smart Cards: Architecture and Programmer's Guide by Zhiqun Chen

Tags: hyperlink, applet, smartcard, javacard, card

From where can I download Java Card Technology for Smart Cards: Architecture and Programmer's Guide by Zhiqun Chen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a for profit book and even if there would be a link online, stackoverflow rules would not allow it to be posted here

Comment: Sorry didn't knew that, I'm a college student wanted to learn about smart card and Java card and was told it's one of the best book to get started with. Can you suggest some free resources.